# How to set option ngx-mydatepicker get MM/yyyy

Tags: html, angular

I don't known how to set the option ngx-mydatepicker to get MM/yyyy. Please help me.
Thank you.

```
<input class="form-control" style="float:none" placeholder="mm/yyyy" ngx-mydatepicker name="mydate"
                  model="buyDate" [options]="myDatePickerOptions" #dp="ngx-mydatepicker" [(ngModel)]="date" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>

 private myDatePickerOptions: INgxMyDpOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy'
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code for formatting [Link to code](https://github.com/kekeh/ngx-mydatepicker/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=dateFormat&type=), the module does not allow you to have dates in that format. You will need to a custom formatting. Take a look at [Angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment)

What is the initial format of your dates?